# Not able to sign out from yahoomail using webdriver

Tags: python

I have just started learning webdriver using python .
I am trying to logging into yahoo , and then perform signout .
I am able to login but while trying to click on "sign-out" , it says "element not visible".

I have gone through the post "[Selenium WebDriver Yahoo mail sign out error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059671/selenium-webdriver-yahoo-mail-sign-out-error)" and tried in similar way but its not working .

I am using chrome .
Here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.yahoomail.com")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("login")
elem.send_keys("email-id")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("passwd")
elem.send_keys("pwd")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(120)
mnEle = driver.find_element_by_id("yucs-profile")
driver.implicitly_wait(120)
sbEle = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Sign Out')]").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(120)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(mnEle).perform()
driver.implicitly_wait(120)
driver.find_element_by_id(sbEle).click()
```

Thanks,
Priyanka

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on the signout anchor tag ID. I think you are trying to find the text which isn't working for you. So you can try this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.yahoomail.com")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("login")
elem.send_keys("email-id")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("passwd")
elem.send_keys("pwd")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(120)
mnEle = driver.find_element_by_id("yucs-profile")
driver.implicitly_wait(120)

# you need to find the signout button instead of an anchor tag with signout text
sbEle = driver.find_element_by_id("yucs-signout").click()

driver.implicitly_wait(120)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(mnEle).perform()
driver.implicitly_wait(120)
driver.find_element_by_id(sbEle).click()
```

Comment: I tried this but it still shows same message "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visi
ble
  (Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.65)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)